# Streaming mp4 live broadcasting video content over websocket to mediasource element

Tags: javascript, video, mp4, media-source

I have a number of questions related to streaming (via websockets) on-air broadcasting h264 video to MediaSource element inside of mp4 container:

- Do i need `ftyp`? If i do, do i need it to be in the same Uint8Array as `moov`?
- Do i need to send every mp4 box separatly or can i hope that `sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(data)` will sort them out?
- Do i need to send `moof` and `mdat` together or should the be fed in different calls to `sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(data)`?
- Do i need any other kind of boxes, specifically for indicating timestamps?
- Do i need to indicate to MediaSource element when to start playing appended data chunks?
- Do i have to set any duration/timestampOffset-related things?
- Is there any crucial points in `moov` box i should be aware of when trying to produce live stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `moov` box is the initialization segment and it is required so the decoder knows what it needs to decode, any other boxes should be ignored (never tried to include a fragment at initialization, so maybe that's not allowed) so no need to remove them.

`moof` and `mdat` boxes should be appended in a single call (those are the segments), no other boxes are needed. As far as I know timestamp data is included in the `moof` box, so no need to add anything else.

Basically you are good with a sequence of `moov [moof mdat]+`.